# Is there a module that can count occurrences of a list of strings in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nltk, counter

I have defined a list that reads the contents of a number of files and stores all of them.
How do I create a dataframe, with each filename in a row, and the corresponding columns count the occurrence of each word and output it.

For the sake of example, assume this is all well-defined (but I can provide original code if needed):

```
#define list
words = [ file1_contents, file2_contents ]

file1_contents = "string with dogs, cats and my pet sea turtle that lives in my box with my other turtles."
file2_contents = "another string about my squirrel, box turtle (who lives in the sea), but not my cat or dog".

filter_words = ["cat", "dog", "box turtle", "sea horse"]
```

Output would be something like this:

```
output = {'file1'{'cat': 1, 'dog':1, 'box turtle': 1, 'sea horse': 0}, 'file2'{ ...}}
```

I have attached an image of my end goal. I am just beginning to use python, so I'm not too sure about what package/module I would use here? I know pandas lets you work with dataframes.

I had the idea of using `Counter` from `collections`

```
from collections import Counter
z = ['blue', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red']
Counter(z)
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'yellow': 1})
```

BUT, here is where I am stuck. How do I organise a table in python which would look like the attached image?

Example output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is loop be each file content, filter  values from list `filter_words` by `re.findall`, count by `Counter` and create dictionary for `DataFrame`:

```
file1_contents = "string with dogs, cats and my pet sea turtle that lives in my box with my other turtles."
file2_contents = "another string about my squirrel, box turtle (who lives in the sea), but not my cat or dog."
```

---

```
import re
from collections import Counter

words = {'file1': file1_contents, 'file2':file2_contents}

filter_words = ["cat", "dog", "box turtle", "sea horse"]

out = {}
for k, w in words.items():
    new = []
    for fw in filter_words:
        new.extend(re.findall(r"{}".format(fw),w) )
    out[k] = dict(Counter(new))
print (out)
{'file1': {'cat': 1, 'dog': 1}, 'file2': {'cat': 1, 'dog': 1, 'box turtle': 1}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(out, orient='index').fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
       cat  dog  box turtle
file1    1    1           0
file2    1    1           1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. This is exactly what I was looking for, I think I can change this to fit my needs. Just one quick question - 
re.findall(r"{}".format(fw),w)
What is this line doing? If I read it correctly, you are populating the list new[ ] with values in our list [filter_words], if they are found in the dictionary {words}. Is that correct?

Also, what does out[k] = dict(Counter(new)) do? I thought out was already specified as a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

There are quiet a few things to consider to get this right, such as handling punctuation, plurals, 1 term 2 term words etc.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
# nltk.download('wordnet')
import string
import pandas as pd

def preproc(x): 

    #make translator object
    trans=str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation)
    wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()

    x = ' '.join([wnl.lemmatize(e) for e in x.translate(trans).split()])
    return x

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=filter_words, 
                             ngram_range=(1,2),
                             preprocessor=preproc)

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(words)

pd.DataFrame(columns=filter_words,
            data=X.todense())
```

Output:

```
    cat dog box turtle  sea horse
0   1   1   0           0
1   1   1   1           0
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful

Comment: No worries. Please consider accepting it as the answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks again. Do you mind answering a (hopefully) quick question? When I export my dataframe to csv, the row's are not showing up. For instance row 0, row 1 will not show as the row label, but I get all the columns - any idea why? I actually ended up using the code below by jezrael, as it was a little more easier for me to read and implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
df_st = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1,3):
    filename = 'file'+str(i)+'.txt'
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        list_words = []
        word_count = 0
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                word_count = word_count + 1
                list_words.append(word)

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = (0,),data=Counter(list_words))
    df2['0_word_count'] = word_count
    df2['0_file_name'] = filename
    df_st = df_st.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
df_st

Out[2]:

    (who    0_file_name 0_word_count    about   and another box but cat cats    ... pet sea sea),   squirrel,   string  that    the turtle  turtles.    with
0   NaN file1.txt   18  NaN 1.0 NaN 1   NaN NaN 1.0 ... 1.0 1.0 NaN NaN 1   1.0 NaN 1   1.0 2.0
1   1.0 file2.txt   18  1.0 NaN 1.0 1   1.0 1.0 NaN ... NaN NaN 1.0 1.0 1   NaN 1.0 1   NaN NaN
```